# Backbone sends request payload instead of FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, rest, backbone.js

I am trying to post some data to the server using backbone collection's create method like this:

```
this.collection.create(modelData,
{
wait:true,
contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
});
```

Here model data contains a well formatted JSON object. The problem is that the post request always gets cancelled. The data sent is in the form of requestpayload.

Using some REST client 
I am able to post easily because it sends the data using formData instead of requestPayload.

Any takers?

EDIT

This is what i get in network console:

```
Request URL:http://myendpointurlhere.com/
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://localhost:8888
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8888/case/12345
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
model:{"startDate":"19/5/2014","acute":"true","terminal":"true","comment":"","name":"Hypothyroidism","caseId":"4872585904914432"}
```

**EDIT 2**

For some reason this is what worked for me. Let me know your thoughts on this:

```
this.collection.create({},
{
  data:modelData,
  wait:true,
  emulateJSON:true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the request sent as formData you should use the `emulateJSON:true` options with your request. [From the docs:](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON)

> If you're working with a legacy web server that can't handle requests encoded as application/json, setting Backbone.emulateJSON = true; will cause the JSON to be serialized under a model parameter, and the request to be made with a application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME type, as if from an HTML form.

```
this.collection.create(modelData,
{
    wait:true,
    emulateJSON:true
});
```

Or, if all your requests need to use `emulateJSON` you can set it globally with `Backbone.emulateJSON=true;`

Update:

If you actually need to send the FormData object to server, you will need to modify sync for your models/collection to generate it yourself before you send it to the server. Here's something you can try (not tested):

```
var YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function(method, model, options){
        options = options || {};
        var formData = new FormData();

        var json = model.toJSON();
        _.each(json, function(value, key){
             formData.append(key, value);
        });     

        options.data = formData;
        options.emulateJSON = true; // Important because your sending formdata
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.sync.call(this, method, model, options);           
    }
});
```

http://mrjoelkemp.com/2013/09/backbone-js-model-save-without-the-emulatejson-model-attribute/ provides a good example of how this works.

Comment: See my second Edit and provide your reviews please.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you have to manually create your own `FormData` store and send it as `data` if you want `$.ajax` to send you the data as a `FormData` and not as `Request payload`.

You can do it by this :

```
var formData = new FormData();

for ( key in modelData ) {
    data.append(key, modelData[key]);  
}

this.collection.create(modelData, {
    wait:true,
    data: formData,
    processData: false
});
```

You can check out the [JsBin demo here](http://jsbin.com/maluguli/1/edit?html,js,console,output) Just open the developer tools and see that you have what you need in the `FormData` of the request.

Comment: See my second Edit and provide your reviews please.